# In which folder or where actually the fsimage and edit log files are stored for the namenode to read and merge during the startup?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

When a namenode starts up, it reads HDFS state from an image file, fsimage and then applies the edits from the edit log file.

If I am not wrong , the Name node starts up means when we write start-all.sh. So during this start up time I think it read the fsimage and edit logs and merge them . But from which folder or from which location it actually read both these things?

Comment: If you think the following answer helped you, accept the answer which would be useful for others while referring.

Answer (score 7):

In hadoop-1.x start-all.sh script internally performs two operation `start-dfs.sh` and `start-mapred.sh`. start-dfs.sh will start all daemons required for hdfs ie : datanode, namenode, secondary namenode

The checkpoint operation(applying edit logs to fsimage) happens during namenode start and this activity can be configured during namenode runs by tuning the parameter `hdfs-site.xml --> dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period` .

During namenode starts namenode daemons loads fsimage from the directory specified in `hdfs-site.xml -> dfs.name.dir.` This property should have been overridden otherwise it would take the default value  (`file:///tmp/dfs/name/`)

Location of the edit logs can be found by checking the value of `hdfs-site.xml -> dfs.name.edits.dir`. default value of dfs.name.edits.dir is ${dfs.name.dir}.

The above property names are changed in hadoop-2.0

Answer (score 0):

When you start daemons,namenode will check the configuration xml file named

> core-site.xml

located in your hadoop conf folder. In my system it is located at usr/lib/hadoop/conf which is hadoop installed directory.

In that configuration file you can see,

```
<configuration>
     <property>
         <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
         <value>/var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/${user.name}</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

In this code /var/lib/hadoop-0.20/cache/ is the location of fsimage, fstime and edits log.

If in case of namenode failure for some particular time fsimage data will be stored in secondynamenode temporarily, and after namenode get recovered temporary data will be stored in fsimage.

Answer (score 0):

below is the location where you can find edits and fsimage files..

/app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name/current

[core-site.xml]

```
<property><name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name><value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
```

i believe this will help you..